# Binding scope to item in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

This is extremely hard for me to explain in the title so I am just going to give an example to explain better:

I want to pass a function such as `()=>{console.log(this.operatorValue)}`,  as a parameter to recursive `traverseCriteria` function.

**traverseCriteria Function**

```
  function traverseCriteria(arr, parameters,fn) {
        for (const item of arr) {
          if (Array.isArray(item))
          this.traverseCriteria(item, parameters)
          else if (typeof item === 'object'){
              item.operatorValue = parameters[item.Property]
             console.log(item.operatorValue)  ///<-- REPLACE THIS WITH fn()
            //fn()
          }
        }
        return arr
      }
```

**In the above function I want to be able to replace `console.log(item.operatorValue)` with fn();**

```
    const criteria =  [
            "and",
            {
              "Collection": "persons",
              "Property": "phone",
              "operator": "eq",
              "operatorValue": "23138213"
            },
            {
              "Collection": "persondetails",
              "Property": "country",
              "operator": "eq",
              "operatorValue": "Russia"
            }
          ]
    const parameters = { phone: "23138213", "country": "Russia" };
```

**function call:**

```
  traverseCriteria(criteria,parameters,()=>{console.log(this.operatorValue)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to set the `this` value of a function:

```
fn.call(item)
```

However, keep in mind that arrow functions don't have their own `this` value, so to make this work you have to pass a "normal" function.

Comment: I think that answers my question. However, out of curiosity, what if I also wanted to access another parameter inside the function such as say.. the array itself. Or may be a variable that was declared just before `for (const item of arr)`

Comment: You can pass any number of arguments to the function, e.g. `fn.call(item, arr)` would set `this` to `item` and pass `arr` as first argument to the function. However, in that case it might be better to forget about `this` and go with a more common "interface", e.g. the one used by array's [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (where the callback is passed the current item, the item's index and the array as arguments).

Comment: Thank you very much, you comment was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass `item.operatorValue` as argument to your function

```js
  function traverseCriteria(arr, parameters, fn) {
        for (const item of arr) {
          if (Array.isArray(item))
          this.traverseCriteria(item, parameters)
          else if (typeof item === 'object'){
              item.operatorValue = parameters[item.Property]
            fn(item)
          }
        }
        return arr
      }
```

and then call it

```js
traverseCriteria(criteria, parameters,(item) => { console.log(item.opValue) });
```

Comment: Yes but the thing is that I may not always want to perform action on `operatorValue ` I may want to do something with `operatorValue ` and some other property the other time. I don't wan't to hardcode property name inside traverseCriteria

Comment: @SamuraiJack: You can just pass the whole `item` as argument to the callback.

Comment: @SamuraiJack it seems like you are flattening array with recursive function. You might want to consider to just use `Array.prototype.flat` to remove recursion and make your code simpler

Answer (score 0):

The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Arrow function cannot be used every where, not for this case, passing normal function will work!.

Great article: [https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256#:~:text=Unlike%20regular%20functions%2C%20arrow%20functions,closest%20non%2Darrow%20parent%20function](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256#:%7E:text=Unlike%20regular%20functions%2C%20arrow%20functions,closest%20non%2Darrow%20parent%20function).

Answer (score 0):

For me the most valuable approach was to separate the actual processing of a criteria item from the `traverseCriteria` method thats sole responsibility should be the iteration of a criteria array structure via a [*context aware* `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Using_thisArg).

Thus the footprint of `traverseCriteria` remains small and one can focus on the actual processing task. The implementation of the latter then can be more easily refactored to e.g. the OP's goals.

Since it was not quite clear what those goals actually are, the approach provides two solutions to what was possibly ask for. First, this additionally passed handler could be understood to be a method that operates upon a criteria item. In this case one just applies the specific criteria item via [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to this handler. Second, and this is what I would propose, one should see this handler as the most generic form of an item specific callback. Thus one, snapshot-like, passes all the relevant data to it. How to implement such a callback handler then is left to whoever consumes the `traverseCriteria` method.

```js
function processContextualItem(item, idx, arr) {
  const { target, params, itemHandler, genericCallback } = this;
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {

    target.traverseCriteria(item, params, itemHandler, genericCallback);

  } else if (item && (typeof item === 'object')) {

    item.operatorValue = params[item.Property];

    // I want to be able to replace
    // console.log(item.operatorValue)
    // with fn();

    // e.g. *item specific* with bound item reference.
    itemHandler.call(item/*, idx, arr, .., ...*/);

    // e.g. *most generic* for any kind of "callback".
    genericCallback(item, idx, arr, params, target);
  }
}


function traverseCriteria(arr, params, itemHandler, genericCallback) {
  arr.forEach(processContextualItem, {
    target: this,
    params,
    itemHandler,
    genericCallback
  });
  return arr;
}
const testType = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
  traverseCriteria
};


function itemMethod() {
  console.log('\n this.operatorValue :', this.operatorValue);
}
function genericCallback(item, idx, arr, params, target) {
  console.log('\n item.operatorValue :', item.operatorValue);
  console.log('\n idx, arr, params, target:', idx, arr, params, target);
}
const params = { phone: "23138213", "country": "Russia" };

const criteria =  [
  "foo", {
    "Collection": "persons",
    "Property": "phone",
    "operator": "eq",
    "operatorValue": "23138213"
  }, {
    "Collection": "persondetails",
    "Property": "country",
    "operator": "eq",
    "operatorValue": "Russia"
  }, [
    "bar", {
      "Collection": "persons",
      "Property": "phone",
      "operator": "eq",
      "operatorValue": "23138213"
    },
    "baz"
  ]
];


testType.traverseCriteria(criteria, params, itemMethod, genericCallback);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```